# Bakbone model extend filtering a json

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am very new in backbone js.

I am trying to filter some specific key and values in backbone js model extend here is the code below.

```
 var items = ["open","close"];
 var ReportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
      return tab+".json";
    }
 });
```

where tabe is dynamic json file name.In my json file many key value pair are there but I want to load only those key which is mentioned in items list.
I saw some where using parse function but that a;so did not work out.Please do let me know how to filter the specific keys form json using the backbone.
I also tried creating a dict from json and pass it to model like.

```
     var ReportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     "open":{.......}
      });
```

but there I am getting issue.

> throw new Error('A "url" property or function must be specified');

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some steps to be succesfull on your task.

First a note about the error: Backbone expects a string on the `url` property while you're passing a function. If you want to use a function to return your url dinamically use `urlRoot`.

Now onto the real coding:
since you talk about a json file that has multiple key value, maybe you should declare your model as a key-value object, and then create a `Backbone.Collection` that will wrap your models.
A `Backbone.Collection` expose a lot of utilities that can help us modeling the results, in this case by using the [where()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) function of our collection you will be able to filter the data after you have retrieved from the remote file.

Alternatively to filter your collection if you need more control over the function you can always call the undescore function [filter()](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) .

Please refer to the official documentation of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) and [backbone](http://backbonejs.org), as you will find a lot of functions that can help you and most of them have an example that shows how to use them.

Now that we have everything lets create our Backbone.Collection that will wrap your already defined model:

```
var ReportCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: ReportModel,
   urlRoot: function(){
      return  'yoururl.json';
   }
});
```

now if you want to filter the result you can simply fetch the collection and perform a filter on it:

```
var myReports = new ReportCollection();
//call the fetch method to retrieve the information from remote
myReports.fetch({success: function(){
   //the collection has been fetched correctly, call the native where function with the key to be used as a filter.
   var filteredElements = myReports.where({my_filter_key : my_filter_value});

});
```

in your filteredElements you will have an array of object made up of all the model that matched the key/value passed to the where function.
If you need a new Collection from that you just need to pass the result as argument: `var filteredCollection = new ReportCollection(filteredElements);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.pick()`](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) in the parse method as shown below:

```js
var items = ["open", "close"];
var ReportModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return tab + ".json";
  },
  parse: function(response) {
    return _.pick(response, items);
  }
});
```